# Задача со структурами

Tags: ассемблер

Не выходит сделать задание с структурами. Необходимо вводить поля структуры для каждого объекта, для того что бы остановить ввод нужно нажать 'n' в соответствующем запросе. Скорей всего ошибка кроется в определение структуры (в массивах полей) либо в самом вводе выводе.

Компилировал так
tasm /zi lr3.asm
tlink /v lr3

```
ASSUME CS: CODE_SEG, DS: DATA_SEG

STUDENT STRUC
    NUMBER  DB  3,?,2   DUP(' ')
    FIO     DB  19,?,18 DUP(' ')
    SPEC    DB  6,?,5   DUP(' ')
    AGE     DB  6,?,5   DUP(' ')
    CR_LF   DB          0DH,0AH
STUDENT ENDS

DATA_SEG SEGMENT

    STUDENTS    STUDENT 30  DUP(<>)
    ENDSTR      DB      '$'
    ENTER_NUM   DB      'ENTER YOUR POS: $'
    ENTER_SPEC  DB      'ENTER YOUR GROUP: $'
    ENTER_FIO   DB      'ENTER YOUR FIO: $'
    ENTER_AGE   DB      'ENTER YOUR AGE: $'
    NEWL        DB      0DH,0AH,'$'
    HEADER      DB      '# NAME              SPEC AGE   ',0DH,0AH
    LINE        DB      '-|-----------------|----|------',0DH,0AH,'$'
    SPACE       DB      ' $'
    CHOOSE      DB      'PRESS `n` TO PRINT STRUC AND EXIT, OR TO CONTINUE PRESS ENTER',0DH,0AH,'$'

DATA_SEG ENDS

CODE_SEG    SEGMENT

START:
;DEFINE DATA SEGMENT---------------------
    MOV AX,DATA_SEG
    MOV DS,AX
    XOR AX,AX

;TYPE Y/N TO CONTINUE--------------------
    MOV SI,0
ENTERING_DATA:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,CHOOSE
    INT 21H
    MOV AH,01H
    INT 21H
    CMP AL,'n'
    JE PRINT_SHORT

;ENTERING DATA-----------------------------------------
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,ENTER_NUM
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,0AH
    LEA DX,STUDENTS[SI].NUMBER
    INT 21H
    CALL NEW_LINE

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,ENTER_FIO
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,0AH
    LEA DX,STUDENTS[SI].FIO
    INT 21H
    CALL NEW_LINE

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,ENTER_SPEC
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,0AH
    LEA DX,STUDENTS[SI].SPEC
    INT 21H
    CALL NEW_LINE

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,ENTER_AGE
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,0AH
    LEA DX,STUDENTS[SI].AGE
    INT 21H
    CALL NEW_LINE

    INC SI
    JMP ENTERING_DATA
;END OF ENTERING DATA--------------------------------------

;PRINT SHORT
PRINT_SHORT:
    CALL PRINT_HEADER
    JMP PRINT

;PRINT STRUCTURE-------------------------------------------
PRINT:
    DEC SI

    MOV AH,40H
    MOV CL,[STUDENTS[SI].NUMBER+1]
    LEA DX,STUDENTS[SI].NUMBER+2
    INT 21H
;PRINT SPACES-----------
    MOV CL,2
    SUB CL,[STUDENTS[SI].NUMBER+1]
@LOOP1:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,SPACE
    INT 21H
    LOOP @LOOP1

    MOV AH,40H
    MOV CL,[STUDENTS[SI].FIO+1]
    LEA DX,STUDENTS[SI].FIO+2
    INT 21H
;PRINT SPACES-----------
    MOV CL,18
    SUB CL,STUDENTS[SI].FIO+1
@LOOP2:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,SPACE
    INT 21H
    LOOP @LOOP2

    MOV AH,40H
    MOV CL,[STUDENTS[SI].SPEC+1]
    LEA DX,STUDENTS[SI].SPEC+2
    INT 21H
;PRINT SPACES-----------
    MOV CL,5
    SUB CL,[STUDENTS[SI].SPEC+1]
@LOOP3:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,SPACE
    INT 21H
    LOOP @LOOP3

    MOV AH,40H
    MOV CL,[STUDENTS[SI].AGE+1]
    LEA DX,STUDENTS[SI].AGE+2
    INT 21H
;PRINT SPACES-----------
    MOV CL,5
    SUB CL,[STUDENTS[SI].AGE+1]
@LOOP4:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,SPACE
    INT 21H
    LOOP @LOOP4

    MOV AX,0
    CMP AX,SI
    JLE PRINT
;END OF PRINTING STRUCTURE----------------------------------------

;EXIT OF PROGRAM--------------------------------------------------
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H

;PROCEDURES-------------------------------------------------------
NEW_LINE:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,NEWL
    INT 21H
    RET
PRINT_NUM:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,ENTER_NUM
    INT 21H
    RET
PRINT_SPEC:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,ENTER_SPEC
    INT 21H
    RET
PRINT_FIO:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,ENTER_FIO
    INT 21H
    RET
PRINT_AGE:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,ENTER_AGE
    INT 21H
    RET
PRINT_HEADER:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,HEADER
    INT 21H
    RET
;END OF PROCEDURES-------------------------------------------------------

CODE_SEG ENDS
END START
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое что бросается в глаза без подробного разбора и отладчика: вы в цикле увеличиваете `SI` на единицу, а нужно - на размер структуры:

```
INC SI               ; неправильно!
ADD SI, TYPE STUDENT ; правильно
```

Может ещё какие глюки есть, но этот в любом случае нужно исправить в первую очередь, из-за него вы просто на каждом цикле затираете уже введённые данные.

То же касается и вывода, откатываться нужно на `TYPE STUDENT`.

И, ради Исидора Севильского, не пишите всё в "одну простыню", форматируйте исходники!

---

Что касается других ошибок. Под отладчиком чётко видно, что не срабатывает вот это условие, поэтому и выводится мусор:

```
MOV AX,0   ; попробуйте прокрутить эти операции
CMP AX,SI  ; в голове и представить что с чем сравнивается
JLE PRINT  ; и при каких условиях будет переход
```

Правильно:

```
CMP SI, 0
JG PRINT
```

Ну и: забыт перевод строки между выводом записей, из-за этого всё мешается в кучу, плюс мусор затирает уже выведеные данные. Итого:

```
LOOP @LOOP4
CALL NEWLINE

CMP SI, 0
JG PRINT
```

Ну и последняя мелочь: вот здесь нельзя надеяться, что код завершения (AL) будет выставлен в каких-либо побочных операциях, напрямую не связанных с явным указанием результата работы программы:

```
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
```

Хотя нет, не последняя :) Раз уж это не `.TINY` - где стек?

Comment: поменял, в консоль так и не выводит то что нужно(всякие символы вывелись)

Comment: Отладчиком пользоваться пробовали?

Comment: @Bohdan, см. обновление ответа.